# Check empty field with validate

Tags: javascript, validation

I have this code:

```
$("#formulario").validate({
ignore: [],
rules: {
        nome:{required: true},
        contato:{required: true},
        telefone:{required: true},
         cidade:{required: true},
        email:{required: true, email: true},
        mensagem:{required: true},
      },
  });
```

It works perfectly!

But I inserted in the form a hidden field called URL and the above code should only be executed IF that hidden field is EMPTY.

How to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, the hidden input field has id `url`.

You can wrap your function call inside an if condition in which you can check if the hidden field with id `url` is empty or not.

```
var hiddenField = $('#url');
 if( hiddenField.val().length === 0 ) {
       $("#formulario").validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        nome:{required: true},
        contato:{required: true},
        telefone:{required: true},
        cidade:{required: true},
        email:{required: true, email: true},
        mensagem:{required: true},
       }
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do some validation in the jQuery validator...

```
$("#formulario").validate({
ignore: [],
rules: {
        newHiddenField:{maxlength: 0},
        ...
        nome:{required: true},
        contato:{required: true},
        telefone:{required: true},
﻿        cidade:{required: true},
        email:{required: true, email: true},
        mensagem:{required: true},
      }
});
```

Or you could check the field is empty then call the validator if it is...

```
let isHiddenFieldEmpty = Boolean($("#formulario input[name=newHiddenField]").val().length === 0);

isHiddenFieldEmpty && $("#formulario").validate({
ignore: [],
rules: {
        nome:{required: true},
        contato:{required: true},
        telefone:{required: true},
﻿        cidade:{required: true},
        email:{required: true, email: true},
        mensagem:{required: true},
      }
});
```